# Perform arithmetic within c macro

Tags: c, linux, pointers

While porting a library i encountered the following problem. There is a macro definition which have a hardware equivalent-

```
#define PREFETCH(addr) HW_PREFETCH((const volatile void *)addr)
```

I need to port another macro PREFETCH_ADDR_OFF(addr,offset) to HW_PREFETCH(addr). I tried following but isn't working. Is there a way to perform arithmetic within c macro ?

```
#define PREFETCH_ADDR_OFF(addr,offset) PREFETCH(addr+offset)
```

Following is the compilation error:

> pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic

EDIT-
Here is what worked for me-

```
#define PREFETCH(addr) HW_PREFETCH(addr)
#define PREFETCH_ADDR_OFF(addr,offset) PREFETCH((((char*)addr)+offset))
```

Comment: Yes - you can, but why would you want to when you could make an inline function (which the compiler will optimise away) which will make life easier in the long run?

Comment: It doesn't look like a C++ question so C++ tag here seems wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to `#define  PREFETCH_ADDR_OFF( _base, _offset)  __builtin_prefetch( static_cast<uint8_t*>( (_base) ) + (_offset), 1, 1  )`

Comment: @VictorGubin I have to use HW_PREFETCH(addr) specifically which is predefined in library i am porting to.

Comment: @DanM That was to reach wider audience. I assume c++ user are familiar to macro/pointer constructs and may be able to help. If it violate SO guidelines i'll remove it.

Comment: @raj_gt1 prefetch is actually a CPU/platform feature, i.e. pre-load memory into CPU cache before access it. I expect HW_PREFETCH is actually `#define HW_PREFETCH(_base)  __builtin_prefetch( (_base), 1, 0 )`

Comment: @VictorGubin: After some more macro wrapper It is finally defined to following assembly instruction  "asm volatile ("pref %[type], %[off](%[rbase])" : : [rbase] "d" (address), [off] "I" (offset), [type] "n" (X))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `addr` is a `void*`, and as the compiler says, you cannot do math on a `void*`.

Use a TypeCast to cast the pointer to a byte-pointer, and do math on that.
The result will be a `char*`, which should freely convert to a `void*`

```
#define PREFETCH_ADDR_OFF(addr,offset) PREFETCH((((char*)addr)+offset))
```

Comment: problem persist after editing to PREFETCH((((const volatile void *))addr)+offset). I have edited the question btw.

Comment: @raj_gt1 nothing changed: you're still trying to do arithmetic on a `void *`, and it still isn't legal.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a `void*` and a `char*`?

Comment: i tried that too but it was still giving me same error. I realized i need to change Ist macro too. Edited the question for what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

How big are the things that the offset refers to? If they are bytes then you need to use a (char *) If they are ints then use (int *). Pointer arithmetic increases the pointer by the amount needed to step over the things that the pointer points to. You cannot use void *. It will not work. A (void *) tells the compiler its a general purpose pointer. A (void *) is typically cast to a pointer of the type you want before the pointer can be used to access data, or do pointer arithmetic.

"Macros" are, basically, just text substitution. If you get really stuck then you can use save-temps to see the file after the substitution but before it is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you can't do pointer arithmetic on a `void*` and that has nothing to do with macros, but the C standard and common sense. How big is a `void` object?

Therefore you'll have to cast to a type which you *can* do arithmetic on, portably:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define PREFETCH_ADDR_OFF(addr,offset) PREFETCH( (uintptr_t)(addr) + (offset) )
```

Comment: Since the wanted ultimate result is a pointer, why prefer type `uintptr_t`, which is optional, over type `char *`, which is guaranteed to exist?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Because it solves the whole qualifier mess you might otherwise get, when the caller passes on some type with other qualifiers than the expected `volatile const type*`. You can't wildly convert between pointers with non-matching qualifiers, but you can wildly convert to/from an integer type.

Comment: I don't follow.  Ignoring for the moment the fact that the intent seems to be that the macro arguments will be integer constants, C explicitly allows a pointer to one object type to be converted to a pointer to a different object type.  Since it also distinguishes `const` / `volatile` / `restrict`-qualified types, in all combinations, as distinct object types, and moreover explicitly allows converting between pointers to qualified types and pointers to unqualified ones, I'm inclined to think that you *can* arbitrarily convert between pointers to differently qualified base object types.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Suppose the caller passes on a `type* const` pointer. Ignoring what the standard says, casting such a pointer first to `char*` and then to `const volatile void*` is rather fishy code and compilers/static analysers will likely whine about it. In addition, there's also the issue saying that you aren't actually allowed to do pointer arithmetic on a pointer which does not point at an array - doing so is formally UB. Getting rid of the pointer arithmetic entirely gives robust code.

Comment: I suppose you meant a `const type *`, as making the pointer itself `const` has no relevant impact.  To the extent that this is a concern, converting to `const char *` instead of `char *` would address it.  But inasmuch as the standard declares the result of converting a non-zero integer to a pointer type to be implementation-defined, I think "entirely robust code" is an overstatement.  This activity relies fundamentally on implementation characteristics.  In the unlikely event of an implementation where exactly one of `uintptr_t` and `char *` worked, I would expect it to be the latter.